# Data sent from service to activity is been lost. Why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to android and I have the following code in my Service :

```
int icon = R.drawable.gcm_notification;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String notificationText = "Message From SimplePay";

//get the notification service
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon,notificationText,when);
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

String messageBody = "You have " + 1 + " payment request pending";

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,InvoiceActivity.class);

notificationIntent.putExtra("invoice",message);

 System.out.println(message);

//always create a new activity! So recent values get updated
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,title,messageBody,intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
```

and I can see that `message` that I'm passing to intent is present (i.e its not `null`) . But on my `InvoiceActivity` side when I try to get the `message` value back I get `null` all time. I use the following code in `InvoiceActivity` like this:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 message = extras.getString("invoice");
 System.out.println(message); //always null
```

I'm not sure why this happens. Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which method are you catching the data

Comment: @StinePike: OnCreate Method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for the service: (Make sure you are using the correct intent inside onReceive. onReceive receives an intent; the one that started the service. I noticed that when Eclipse creates onReceive the default name for the Intent parameter is "intent"(You do not want to use this one). Also, why are you using the variable context instead of the keyword this? The Service class extends ContextWrapper which extends Context.

```
package com.example.solution;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Serv extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String message = "Hello";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String notificationText = "Message From SimplePay";

        //get the notification service
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notificationText,when);
        String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);

        String messageBody = "You have " + 1 + " payment request pending";

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,InvoiceActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.putExtra("invoice",message);



        //always create a new activity! So recent values get updated
        PendingIntent intentp = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,title,messageBody,intentp);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Here are the Main Activity (Launcher).

```
package com.example.solution;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        startService(new Intent(this,Serv.class));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(this,Serv.class));
}
}
```

and here is InvoiceActivity

```
package com.example.solution;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

public class InvoiceActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    Log.e("MESSAGE",getIntent().getExtras().getString("invoice"));
}
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if your activity is running, the new intent is probably delivered in onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    message = getIntent().getStringExtra("invoice");
    System.out.println(message); //always null 
}
```